# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES

Tags: mysql, xampp

Al correr el comando **php artisan serve** me sale el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravelcrud and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Mis datos de conexión son:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelbd
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Hola, solo por confirmar cosas que pueden ser obvias, en db_password no estás indicando nada (y el usuario root necesita la clave), está así en tu local o es que no lo colocaste porque no querías que se viera el password acá?.

Comment: No tengo contraseña por eso esta vacio

Comment: Para conectarte desde el mysqlworkbench o desde la terminal usas el usuario root sin contraseña también?

Comment: Si, siempre ha sido así

Comment: Debes entrar a tu panel de suministraron (phpmyadmin) y comprobar los usuarios para ver que todo está correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Quiere decir que se está intentando conectar la aplicación a la base de datos con el usuario root pero éste último está configurado con una contraseña.

Indicaste que te conectas desde el workbench sin colocar el password pero debe ser porque al crear la conexión la primera vez indicaste que querías almacenar la contraseña.

Puedes intentar resetear la clave del usuario root [Resetear clave root](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), pero como tienes acceso desde el workbench también puedes crear un nuevo usuario con el cual se conecte la aplicación.

[Crear nuevo usuario](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html)

Una vez que lo hayas creado modifica el archivo .env con esos datos. Recuerda que debes asignarle o bien permisos de DBA a ese nuevo usuario o los permisos necesarios sobre el esquema laraveldb.

Para crear un usuario con privilegios de DBA (Administrador de base de datos) debes entrar al workbench e ir a la pestaña de administración, alli pulsar sobre usuarios y provilegios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez allí pulsar abajo en el boton agregar cuenta, seguidamente colocar los datos de la cuenta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego ir a la pestaña roles administrativos y marcar la opción DBA.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo pulsar el boton aplicar ubicado abajo a la derecha.