# Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given

Tags: php, mysql

El siguiente codigo me genera este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql)
> must be of type mysqli, bool given in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\index.php:14 Stack trace: #0
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\index.php(14): mysqli_query(false, 'SELECT
>
> - FROM u...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\index.php on line 14

Codigo:

```php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])) {
        $alert = 'INgrese su usuario y su clave';
    }else {
        require_once ("conexion.php");
        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
        $pass = $_POST['clave'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuarios = '$user' AND clave ='$pass'");
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($result > 0) {

            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['active'] = true;
            $_SESSION['idUser'] = $data['idusuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];
            $_SESSION['email']  = $data['email'];
            $_SESSION['user']   = $data['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['rol']    = $data['rol'];

            header('location: sistema/');
        }else {
            $alert = 'El usuario o la clave es incorrecto';
            
        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 El codigo del archivo conexion.php es el siguiente:
$host       ='localhost';
$user       ='root';
$password   =' ';
$db         ='facturacion';

$conection  = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
if ($conection) {
    echo"Error en la conexion";
}
```

Comment: Lo que te indica el error, es que le estas pasando un booleano en uno de los parametros    seguramente sea la variable `$conection`, edita la pregunta y agrega el codgio del archivo `conexion.php`

Comment: Tal vez @masterguru le dio el toque de humor, pero tiene razón: en lugar de escribir "perdón por la molestia" pon en el título _el problema en cuestión_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Para saber de que error se trata, pon `echo mysqli_connect_error();echo mysqli_error($conection); die();` debajo de la linea que empieza por `$query = ` a ver si te da más información. Y si no llega alli ponlo por encima de esa linea.

Comment: Yo le quitaria la @ a esto: `@mysqli_connect` así obtendrás un mensaje de error más claro pues la @ lo que hace es esconderlo si se produce.

Comment: Listo, ya puse lo que me dijeron, pero el echo mysqli_connect_error();echo mysqli_error($conection); die();  no muesra nada

Comment: pues vaya, quítalo pues... ya es raro, pero bueno, prueba lo otro de la @ que he comentado a ver.

Comment: bueno, ahora si muestra el error: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\conexion.php on line 7

Comment: Vale, pues eso cambia totalmente el escenario... veo que ese problema aquí ha tenido una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/445864/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password  Échale un ojo a ver si te sirve, sino seguro que hay más

Comment: muchas gracias por la  ayuda, ya lo solucione.

Comment: perfecto, me alegro :-)  ... si acaso borra esta pregunta pues no tiene respuesta y el error era otro (el escondido con la @), gracias!